# Custom chooser activity: SecurityException UID n does not have permission to content:// uri

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intent-chooser

I'm building a Chooser app that replaces the native Android Share dialog. It works fine except when I try to share an image from Chrome via longpress image > share image.

I found that Google+ doesn't catch the exception (it crashes) so I can have a look at it via Logcat:

- Do an image search on Google.
- Select an image (this should show the preview)
- Longpress the image
- Choose "Share image"
- My chooser activity pops up
- Select Google+
- Google+ crashes with this error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10130 does not have permission to content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/images/screenshot/15307295588677864462883877407218.jpg [user 0]

My code (simplified):

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    handleIntent();
}

private void handleIntent() {

    // Get intent and payload
    mIntent = getIntent();
    mPayloadIntent = (Intent) mIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT);

    // Nullify some things for queryIntentActivities (or no results will be found)
    mPayloadIntent.setComponent(null);
    mPayloadIntent.setPackage(null);

    // Retrieve a list of targets we can send mPayloadIntent to..
    List<ResolveInfo> targets = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mPayloadIntent, 0);
    // etc...

}

private void onClickTarget(ResolveInfo target) {

    // Prepare..
    ComponentName compName = new ComponentName(
                target.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
                target.activityInfo.name);

    // Build a 'new' shareIntent
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(mPayloadIntent);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
    shareIntent.setComponent(compName);

    // Start the targeted activity with the shareIntent
    startActivity(shareIntent);
    finish();

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActShareReplace"
    android:label="Sharedr"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransparentActivity"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If I look at the documentation for [Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER) it says:

> If you need to grant URI permissions through a chooser, you must specify the permissions to be granted on the ACTION_CHOOSER Intent in addition to the EXTRA_INTENT inside. This means using setClipData(ClipData) to specify the URIs to be granted as well as FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION and/or FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION as appropriate.

I'm not completely sure if this is something my app has to do or if it's the responsibility of the app that invoked the chooser activity - but I would assume it's the latter. My app can't set URI permissions for intents it's receiving, can it?

Anyway, if I inspect the extra's and flags on `mIntent` and `mPayloadIntent` I get:

mIntent only has extras, no flags (as far as I can tell):

> android.intent.extra.CHOSEN_COMPONENT_INTENT_SENDER
>   IntentSender{4fa3901: android.os.BinderProxy@3aec3a6} (android.content.IntentSender)
>
> android.intent.extra.INTENT 
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=image/jpeg flg=0x80001 clip={image/jpeg U:content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/images/screenshot/15307316967108618905323381238187.jpg} (has extras) } (android.content.Intent)
>
> android.intent.extra.TITLE
>   Share via (java.lang.String)

mPayloadIntent:

> android.intent.extra.STREAM 
>   content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/images/screenshot/1530731945132897653908815339041.jpg (android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri)

- FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET
- FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT
- FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION

So `mPayloadIntent` *does* have the `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` but mIntent *does not*. According to the docs it should.

I've read that it's possible that my app consumed the URI permission so [I tried caching the file myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174627/securityexception-permission-denial-opening-provider-org-chromium-chrome-brows) but as soon as I try to access the URI through a ContentResolver, I get a - you guessed it - permission error.

I then realized that I probably shouldn't have to cache the file as Android's native [Chooser Activity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ChooserActivity.java) doesn't seem to do that either. So that's where I'm at now. Back to square one.

Is this a Chrome bug? An Android bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

I'd happily blame Chrome and file a bug report but someone who's working on a similar project (and ran into the same issue) told me Whatsapp has a similar problem. It, too, shares images via a content:// uri.

For completeness, I'm testing this on a Pixel 2016 with Android 8.1. I have no idea what the other guy (who ran into the same issue with WA) is using.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this a Chrome bug? An Android bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

My guess is that it is a client-side bug, coming from people creating `ACTION_CHOOSER` `Intent` objects directly rather than through `Intent.createChooser()`. `Intent.createChooser()` looks like it is taking the flags from what you called `mPayloadIntent` and adds them to `mIntent`.

You should be able to test this yourself. Create a scrap app that creates an  `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` with `EXTRA_STREAM` pointing to some piece of content (e.g., served by `FileProvider`). Then, try invoking your chooser three ways:

1. Wrap the `Intent` via `Intent.createChooser()`
2. Wrap the `Intent` via an `ACTION_CHOOSER` `Intent`, where you follow what the docs say and put the flags on both `Intent` objects
3. Wrap the `Intent` via an `ACTION_CHOOSER` `Intent`, where you skip the flags on the `ACTION_CHOOSER` `Intent`

If I am correct, #1 and #2 will work, and #3 will fail with the same basic failure mode that you're seeing.

If my theory holds up so far, try running the three apps again, but this time use the system chooser. My guess is that the system chooser does get some special benefits from being part of the core OS and all three will work. Otherwise, the developers of Chrome and WhatsApp would have run into this problem in their testing and would have fixed it.

And, if all of this theory holds up... you're somewhat screwed. I would assume that more people use `Intent.createChooser()` than use `ACTION_CHOOSER` directly, as `Intent.createChooser()` is simpler. And, some subset of the people who use `ACTION_CHOOSER` might actually follow the documentation...

<sub>hahahahahahahahaha... *gasp* ...hahahahahahahahahaha!</sub>

...and for those, you're OK. And, some people using `ACTION_CHOOSER` might have a `Uri` in `EXTRA_STREAM` that is world-readable (which isn't a good idea, but it works in your favor here). It will only be for buggy clients that create `ACTION_CHOOSER` manually, fail to set the `Intent` flags properly, but *do* secure their content properly, that you won't be able to correctly process the `Intent`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go. Maybe I can look into Chrome's source code (it's OS), see how they put that intent together. I did find their (custom/extended) FileProvider implementation.

Comment: Bah. It looks like #1, #2 and #3 all have the same issue. The receiving app crashes (or catches the error and just bails out). Also, it looks like `Intent.createChooser()` doesn't add the URI permission flags on the intent or the payload intent so I tried adding those but no cigar.

Comment: Reading more through the code from Android's native [ChooserActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ResolverActivity.java) I found it uses the `startActivityAsCaller()` method to invoke the intent. It's declared in [android/app/Activity.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) and not part of the public API. "This is for the resolver and chooser activities which operate as intermediaries". I think I'm ****ed :(((